# What is the difference between JAVA Runnable class to start thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

**The difference between mode 1 and mode 2 start thread?**

Method 1: I use the same Runnable object to start multiple threads

Method 2: I use different Runnable objects to start multiple threads

```
package com.hbase.a;

public class MyThreadB implements Runnable {
    private  int tik = 100;

    public void run() {
       //do ...
    }

 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // method-1 
        MyThreadB myThreadB = new MyThreadB();
        new Thread(myThreadB).start();
        new Thread(myThreadB).start();
        new Thread(myThreadB).start();
        new Thread(myThreadB).start();
       
        // method -2 
        new Thread(new MyThreadB()).start();
        new Thread(new MyThreadB()).start();
        new Thread(new MyThreadB()).start();
        new Thread(new MyThreadB()).start();

    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot method 3: [`java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: @Abra, The OP is asking what it means for multiple threads to operate on the same `Runnable` instance. How the threads are created, and how they are given that instance is a different question.

Comment: Re, "I [use] Runnable object/objects to start...threads." Don't think of it that way. You aren't using the `Runnable` objects to start the threads, you are using the `Thread#start()` method to start the threads, and you are using the `Thread(r)` constructor to _give_ the threads either one shared `Runnable` instance or four unique `Runnable` instances to operate on.

Answer (score 4):

With the first method, there is one single `MyThreadB` object that is shared between all threads. That means that there is only one `tik` variable, which might  be written and read by all 4 threads. This shared variable could be used to pass information from one thread to another, but this easily leads to unintended behavior (bugs).

With the second method, each thread gets an object of its own. There are 4 independent `MyThreadB` objects, each with a `tik` variable of its own. When one thread changes the `tik` variable in its object, it cannot be seen by the other threads.